# AJAX script disappears after live refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

so I've got 2 AJAX scripts and one of them disappears when the first script is fired.

Script 1:

```
        function myFunction<?php echo $product['sku'] ?>() {
        // AJAX CALL

          var url = "remove.php?isbn=<?php echo $product['sku'] ?>";

          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
              $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #results');
              bs4pop.notice('Το προϊόν αφαιρέθηκε με επιτυχία', {position: 'topcenter', type: 'success'});
            },
            complete: function(){

            }
            });
      };
```

Script 2:

```
  $('#insert').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var loadingText = '<i class="spinner-border float-right spinner-border-sm"></i> Παρακαλω Περιμενετε...';
    if ($(this).html() !== loadingText) {
      $this.data('original-text', $(this).html());
      $this.html(loadingText);
    }
    //Disable our button
    $('.btn-dis').attr("disabled", true);
    $('.checked').attr("disabled", true);

    //The URL that we are sending an Ajax request to.
    var url = "insert.php?woocommerce";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data) {
        bs4pop.notice('Η εισαγωγή έγινε με επιτυχία', {
          position: 'topcenter',
          type: 'success'
        })
        $this.html($this.data('original-text'));
      },
      complete: function () {
        $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #results');
        $('.btn-dis').attr("disabled", false);
        $('.checked').attr("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
```

They are both wrapped into two divs `$('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #results');`, when i click the button that fires the first script the second script disappears.

What seems to be the problem?

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Can you show working example? And please format your code to be readable. `$('#refresh').load()` replaces all content inside `#refresh`. Maybe that's the problem? Is ID unique?

Comment: Do you really want that space in `location.href + ' #results'`?

Comment: @user4642212 For some reason without the space it loads the header twice but it loads the second script, with space it doesn't load the script but it refreshes the data just fine without loading the header twice.

Comment: @Justinas Hello, my bad. Yes the ID is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got it working, i moved the button which fired the second script outside the refresh div and it worked like a charm.